# using pandas df with map

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I want to map my DF values into a string:

```
SQL = """select * from mytable where col1={0} and col2={1}"""
```

I tried this `ListResult = map(lambda x :SQL.format(*x),DF[['Col1','Col2']])`

but the output be like

```
[u'select * from mytable where col1 = C and col2=o', 
 u'select * from mytable where col1 = C and col2=o']
```

How can I generate a list of string completed with the values from my DF (the number of columns may vary according to the SQL)?

---

**EDIT**: add sample and expected result

```
> DF =  

 - Col1 Col2
 - 0     1591354166       12387796
 - 1     1596855166        8833942
 - 2     1626196066       12584655
```

expected result:

```
[select * from mytable where col1=1591354166 and col2=12387796,
 select * from mytable where col1=1596855166 and col2=8833942, 
 select * from mytable where col1=1626196066 and col2=12584655]
```

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least sample of dataframe - 3,4 rows and desired output from sample?

Comment: Yep I can ^^ give me 5 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) for generating `numpy array` from `DataFrame`:

```
SQL = """select * from mytable where col1='{0}' and col2='{1}'"""

print map(lambda x :SQL.format(*x),df[['Col1','Col2']].values)

["select * from mytable where col1='1591354166' and col2='12387796'",
 "select * from mytable where col1='1596855166' and col2='8833942'", 
 "select * from mytable where col1='1626196066' and col2='12584655'"]
```

Comment: I was just missing the `.values`. I like when solution are that easy ^^ thx

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

is that what you want?

```
In [50]: ListResult = df.apply(lambda x: SQL.format(x.Col1, x.Col2), axis=1).tolist()

In [51]: ListResult
Out[51]:
['select * from mytable where col1=1591354166 and col2=12387796',
 'select * from mytable where col1=1596855166 and col2=8833942',
 'select * from mytable where col1=1626196066 and col2=12584655']
```